# I am making a voice assistant in python and I need a code or maybe a module for a wake up system

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

I am using the speech_recognition module for taking voice commands. The problem is that I want a system like Alexa and Google voice assistant has. When we say "Alexa" or "Ok Google" they wake up and start listening. I have the listening function but not the wake up system.

```
def takeCommand():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio =r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
        print(f"Recognized Command: {query}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("I didn't recognize what you said please repeat")
        return "None"

    return query
```

This is the code of the listening function, please help me with this. I need a program that respond to a particular wake up word and then executes this takeCommand() function.

Please don't advise things like this:

```
if takeCommand().lower() == "hey jarvis": 
    print("Yes?")
    takeCommand()
```

Because here in speech_recognition, it waits for some time for the person to speak up and then goes to recognition state, for example, This assistant is working in the background and I am reading some articles on the web. This program is in a loop of going in a "listening" state and "recognition" state even if I am not saying anything. Imagine I said "hey jarvis" but this program was in a "recognition" state at that time, so it will not listen to me.

Comment: This looks more like a system design question than a Python question. I have no experience with this topic, but I would expect something like: You have to run (a task) in a loop that checks something like a wake-up threshold. It may be necessary to buffer the audio stream to not miss "the little details" before the threshold is exceeded. If the threshold is exceeded, the tasks actively records what is said and calls the speak recognition library on that content (like a trigger for your whole module).

Comment: To not permanently lock your whole CPU for that cyclic listening/recording tasks, you may have to go deeper into your operation system/middleware and write or use a special audio driver. Not sure what today's audio drivers deliver w.r.t. buffering. Just some thoughts...